# JQuery match 2 IDs by post-delimiter number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure out a way to streamline a script. I have hundreds of icons each with the id "icon_#-#" where the first # relates to a set that particular icon belongs to, and the second # is unique to that icon within the set. Each relates to a box w/ id "box_#-#" where the #-# relates it to a specific icon. For example, #icon_1-1 relates to #box_1_1 and #icon_1-2 relates to #box_1-2. My code is as follows:

```
    $('#icon_1-1').click(function(){
    $('#box_1-1').fadeIn("500");
    });
```

Obviously, using this method I'd have hundreds of lines. Is there a way to streamline, something like:

```
    $('#icon_[array 1-100]').click(function(){
    $('#box_[array 1-100]').fadeIn("500);
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 // v-------use whatever tag name is correct
$('div[id^="icon_"]').click(function(){
    $('#box_' + this.id.replace( 'icon_', '' ) ).fadeIn("500");
});
```

This uses the the [`attribute-starts-with-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to target elements who's ID attribute starts with `"icon_"`.

I also used the the [`element-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), giving it `div` in order to speed up the selection. You should replace it with the correct tag name.

Then in the handler, we get the ID of the element clicked by using `this.id`, and do a `.replace()` to get rid of the `"icon_"` part of the ID, leaving us with the matching segment of the identifier.

That segment is concatenated onto the `#box_` selector.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LWawu/)

```
$('[id^="icon"]').click(function(){
   var coords = this.id.split("_")[1].split("-");
   $('#box_'+coords[0]+'-'+coords[1]).fadeIn("500");
});
```

that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Would be better to add a data-iconid to your icons.

```
<div class="icon" datai-iconid="##" />wat</div>

$('.icon').click(function() {
    var num = $(this).data('iconid');
    $('#box'+num).fadeIn();
});
```